# RegEx Data Values Javascript white Space

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I am trying to add the correct white space for data i am receiving. currently it shows like this

NotStarted

ReadyforPPPDReview

this is the code i am using

```
.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '$1')
```

"NotStarted" shows correct "Not Started" but "ReadyforPPPDReview" shows "Readyfor P P P D Review" when it should look like this "Ready for PPPD Review"

what is the best way to handle both of these using one regex or function?

Comment: BTW these are values coming back based on if it has been reviewed or not started. so it is dynamic

Comment: How do you plan to let regex engine now the `Readyfor` are two concatenated words?

Comment: well they really shouldnt be. It should display like this "Ready for PPPD Review" the problem i am having is since i added the regex and it is going based off of camel case it comes back as this "Readyfor P P P D Review" not sure how to handle this as well as the "Not Started"

Comment: Should there be camel casing for `for` word too in `ReadyforPPPDReview`? Something like `ReadyForPPPDReview`.

Comment: no unfortunately for is not camel casing thats one of the reasons this has been more difficult then it really should be lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an NLP engine to handle this properly. Here are two approaches with simple regex, both have limitations:

**1. Use list of stop words**

We blindly add spaces before and after the stop words:

```js
var str = 'NotStarted, ReadyforPPPDReview';
var wordList = 'and, for, in, on, not, review, the'; // stop words

var wordListRe = new RegExp('(' + wordList.replace(/, */g, '|') + ')', 'gi');
var result1 = str
  .replace(wordListRe, ' $1 ') // add space before and after stop words
  .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2') // add space between lower case and upper case chars
  .replace(/  +/g, ' ') // remove excessive spaces
  .trim(); // remove spaces at start and end
console.log('str:     ' + str);
console.log('result1: ' + result1);
```

As you can imagine the stop words approach has some severe limitations. For example, words `formula input` would result in `for mula in put`.

**1. Use a mapping table**

The mapping table lists words that need to be spaced out (no drugs involved), as in this code snippet:

```js
var str = 'NotStarted, ReadyforPPPDReview';
var spaceWordMap = {
  NotStarted: 'Not Started',
  Readyfor:   'Ready for',
  PPPDReview: 'PPPD Review'
  // add more as needed
};

var spaceWordMapRe = new RegExp('(' + Object.keys(spaceWordMap).join('|') + ')', 'gi');
var result2 = str
  .replace(spaceWordMapRe, function(m, p1) { // m: matched snippet, p1: first group
    return spaceWordMap[p1] // replace key in spaceWordMap with its value
  })
  .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2') // add space between lower case and upper case chars
  .replace(/  +/g, ' ') // remove excessive spaces
  .trim(); // remove spaces at start and end
console.log('str:     ' + str);
console.log('result2: ' + result2);
```

This approach is suitable if you have a deterministic list of words as input.

Comment: @Pdavis33: I am glad this answer is useful to you. Please consider an upvote as well.